# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop Won't Restart into New Install

Tags: system-installation

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop won't restart into a new install.  The install completes successfully, but it won't start up, and the boot drive is correct.  It just keeps looping around to the GRUB menu.  It's a new ASUS Z490 mobo and i7-10700, but I had the same problem with a new MSI mobo.  There's nothing wrong with either of the mobos because the install disc boots up into "Try Ubuntu" just fine.  The ASUS Q-CODE is F6 when it keeps landing back at the GRUB menu after attempted restart.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: While using the "Try Ubuntu" option, have you tried to run the boot-repair utility? It might be that somehow your GRUB is broken and the utility could fix that.

Comment: No, will try.  The only reason I question that is because I've repeatedly downloaded a fresh install ISO.  A friend has suggested it could be RAM.